# inaccurate data PHP when using POST method

Tags: php

i have a special character issue in my php code.
$customer_code is being retrieved by $_POST method.

when i enter a value with special character(ex. 'D&C') it can POST the exact data.

but in my code.

```
If($customer_code != 'D&C') {//this will return true. i also tried using "
    die($customer_code . ' - D&C'); //will return D&C - D&C
}
```

why does POSTED 'D&C' and static 'D&C' not equal?
i hope someone can help me

Comment: `die()` should not have any code in it

Comment: Run a `var_dump()` on both and see what it actually contains

Comment: Use `!==` in your if. Also, check your PHP encoding by default, and add `<meta charset="yourencoding" />` in your html file

Comment: Is there any leading or trailing space with your submitted value/s?  Try trimming before the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the POST request is working (*as specified in the comments, by using a `var_dump($_POST);` for example*), then it might be an encoding issue.
If you are using an HTML form to reach your PHP page, try adding the following code to the form:

```
<form action="your_page.php" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

More details concerning its usage here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp

And deeper article here:
http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Comment: Doesn't the ampersand (D and C) share the same byte sequence in both ASCII, 8859 and UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help guys but i already solved the problem.

by using str_replace

```
 $customer_code = str_replace("&AMP;","&",$customer_code);
```

special character issue.
still thanks for the effort